# How to combine more than one field in a column in DevExpress MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, partial-views

I am trying to combine more than one field in a column. Like two names(First and Last) of a person. Is it possible to do on DevExpress MVC GridView without changing in `DB query`?

Here is my code in Partial View -

```
    settings.Columns.Add("CompanyName");
    // I need to combine NurseFirstName and NurseLastName into one column and name as NurseName 
    settings.Columns.Add("NurseFirstName"); 
    settings.Columns.Add("NurseLastName");
```

TIA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use a DataItemTemplate to combine the values into one cell on the grid. Something like:

```
settings.Columns.Add(c =>
{
    c.Caption = "Nurse Name";
    c.SetDataItemTemplateContent(t =>
    {
        Html.DevExpress().Label(
            l => {
                l.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", DataBinder.Eval(t.DataItem, "NurseFirstName"), DataBinder.Eval(t.DataItem, "NurseLastName"));
            }).Render();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more robust solution that doesn't mess with templates:

```
    // Add column
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "FullName";
        column.Caption = "Full Name";
        column.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.String;
    });

    // Add the combined values to the column
    settings.CustomUnboundColumnData = (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "FullName")
        {
            string fName = (string)e.GetListSourceFieldValue("FirstName");
            string lName = (string)e.GetListSourceFieldValue("LastName");
            e.Value = string.Format("{0} {1}", fName, lName);
        }
    };
```